# Mail service sends missing mail

Tags: c#, email

I did the mail service. When I debug the data I receive from the database it sends it full but when I run the service it sends some of it. What is the reason of this ?

There are 10 records in the database. It is being sent completely with Debug. When I run the *Windows service* or when I terminate the *debug with F5*, **some part** is being sent(Not all).
I hope I could tell you my problem.

I think the problem is that I do not have a "Header" in my mail. What's your idea ?

Meanwhile, I apologize for my bad english.
Thank you for everything.[Please open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5E8h.png)

```
  public bool SendMail(string Body, string Subject, List<string> ToList)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = From;
        bool ReturnValue = false;
        if (ToList.Count < 0)
        {
            return ReturnValue;
        }

        foreach (string Mailaddress in ToList)
        {
            mail.To.Add(Mailaddress);
        }
        mail.Subject = Subject; 
        mail.Body =  Body ;
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { return true; };
            Client.Send(mail);
            ReturnValue = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MailHelper));
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        return ReturnValue;
    }

 protected MailHelper()
    {
        Client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClient"].ToString());
        From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAddressFrom"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAddressFromDisplayName"].ToString());
        //ToList = new List<string>{"trying@trying.com.tr"};   
        Client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortNumber"]);
        Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
        Client.EnableSsl = true;
    }


<add key="log4net.Config" value="App.config" />
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" />
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
<add key="TimerInterval" value="3000" />
<add key="constr" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MailSending;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>

 DateTime davaTarih = Convert.ToDateTime(row["ModuleDate"]);
                            DateTime sonrakiDurusmaTarihi = Convert.ToDateTime(row["FollowingTrialDate"]);
                            string avukatName = row["Username"].ToString();
                            string esasNo = row["No"].ToString();
                            int countDays = Convert.ToInt32(row["countDays"]);
                            string kisaAciklama = row["ShortDescription"].ToString();
                            string sonrakidurusmaTar = "";

                            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(row["FollowingTrialDate"]) && !DBNull.Value.Equals(row["countDays"]))
                            {
                                sonrakiDurusmaTarihi = Convert.ToDateTime(row["FollowingTrialDate"]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sonrakiDurusmaTarihi = Convert.ToDateTime("");
                                sonrakidurusmaTar = "Sonraki Duruşma Bulunmamaktadır.";
                                // var sonrakiDurusma = DateTime.TryParse(SonrakidurusmaTar, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out sonrakiDurusmaTarihi);  // FollowingTrialDate, null olarak gelirse hata vermesin amacıyla yazıldı.
                            }

                            ModuleSubject = " Mnemonic Hatırlatma Servisi";
                            ModuleBody = "Sayın ilgili, ;\r\n \r\n" +
                                    "Modül: " + ModuleName + ";\r\n" +
                                    "Esas no: " + esasNo + ";\r\n" +
                                    "Dava tarihi: " + davaTarih.ToShortDateString() + ";\r\n" +
                                    "Sonraki duruşma tarihi: " + sonrakiDurusmaTarihi.ToShortDateString() + ";\r\n" +
                                    "Kalan Gün Sayısı: " + countDays + ";\r\n" +
                                    "Kısa açıklama: " + kisaAciklama + ";\r\n\r\n" +
                                    "Bilginize,";

                     MailHelper.Instance.SendMail(ModuleBody, ModuleSubject, ToList);
```

Comment: `mail.Body = Body;` - Where is `Body` populated? That's the most important part of the code to see in order to resolve your problem. Please add it to your question.

Comment: What "part" is being sent and what "part" isn't?  Why do you suspect this has to do with a header, what information suggests that to you?

Comment: Are you getting exceptions? Is there something in your log? What *exactly* is not happening here?

Comment: Make sure the service is running as a user (or admin), not default.  When a service is run in default the environmental variable are not set the same as with a user account. Integrated Security uses the users login account to get users credentials (username and password).  So you would not get the data from the database.  So make sure the windows account in the SQL Server includes the account that the service is using.

Comment: @KobyDouek I edited my code. Can you see it again?

Comment: @David I need to send mail for 10 records. But, 5 of them are being sent. The remaining 5 are not sent. 
According to my research, there is not a header id in my mail, so there is a missing mail.

Comment: @DavidG I do not get any exceptions and there is nothing missing in my log file. Just because of something I do not understand the reason, mails are missing.

Comment: @jdweng I am connecting to Sql Server. I am already connected to sql so I can send mail. The only problem is why the missing mail is being sent?

As it is visual, there are 10 records on sql server. When debugging slowly I am sending all of mail. But when I run the service, only a part of the mail is being sent.

Comment: Try closing the client after each email is sent.  You are creating a new client for each email and I suspect that the new email is being created before the previous email was fully sent.  The closing will make sure each email completes before the next one is created.

Comment: I found the answer. It is being sent incomplete because it sends mail quickly. The solution is this:
I wait six each seconds before and after sending mail, and then there is no problem.

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
Client.Send(mail);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It is being sent incomplete because it sends mail quickly. The solution is this: I wait six each seconds before and after sending mail, and then there is no problem.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000); 
Client.Send(mail); 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
```